# Is there a way to upload a .pdf file online with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So I use this piece of code right here.

```py
Manuscript = browser.find_element_by_id('data-print-book-publisher-interior-file-upload-browse-button').send_keys("/Users/Name/Downloads/FishingLogCombined.pdf")
Manuscript.submit()
```

All I get is an open dialog.  Nothing pasted in the file path option.  Just an open dialog to my files, that is it.  Is there anything I can do?  I've tried many different options and none of them have worked.

Comment: The file dialog is part of the os, not the browser so you can't control it like that. There's a new api in chromium to intercept that but I haven't seen anybody work it out here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this. One is to use sendKeys

```py
driver.find_element_by_id('element-id').sendkeys("path-to-the-file");
```

If this does not work then you have to use `AutoIt` script to do this.

Comment: What about on Linux?

Comment: What if I want to hypothetically sell it as a software..?  How would I use AutoIt?  Also, is the semi colon at the end necessary?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Robot interface in Selenium.
You will have to create an instance  `StringSelection` passing the path as argument `String text = "sampledoc.txt";
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);`

Then copy this to the `Clipboard` interface and set path to the setcontent method.
`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection ,null);`
Now we just have to work on the keyboard keys interaction using `Robot` class in selenium.
Follow the key events as mentioned below and your upload should be successful.

```
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

[References for Robot class from stackexchange](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15499/how-to-handle-file-upload-and-download-using-robot-class)

[References for Robot class from learn automation](http://learn-automation.com/upload-file-in-selenium-webdriver-using-robot-class/)

Comment: This is interesting but you're not showing working code.

Comment: The research that I did already exist and so I have left the code in the hyperlink.
@pguardiario .